# PHP header location function to new php file not working

Tags: php, geolocation

I have uploaded a site in english(http://calvindeveloping.tk) but i want to redirect the user if they are from a french countryto this site path - http://calvindeveloping.tk/fr/index.php, so i used the geolocation plugin, the plugin works... except when i try using it in the php header function like this -

```
if ($geoplugin->countryCode == "FR" || $geoplugin->countryCode == "fr") {
header('Location: calvindeveloping.tk/fr/index.php');
}
```

Here is my full php code for the english version of the site, placed just before the html code.

```
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();

$extra = 'fr/index.php';
if ($geoplugin->countryCode == "FR" || $geoplugin->countryCode == "fr") {
header('Location: calvindeveloping.tk/fr/index.php');
exit();
}
?>
```

Please help as this doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that exit() function and replace your location function with the below function i wrote.

```
  header("Location: http://www.calvindeveloping.tk/fr/index.php");
```

Modified version of your code

```
 if ($geoplugin->countryCode == "FR" || $geoplugin->countryCode == "fr") {
 header("Location:http://www.calvindeveloping.tk/fr/index.php");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for header should be

```
header('Location: http://calvindeveloping.tk/fr/index.php');
```

Sice you are

Comment: what is the error that you see? i suggest you to try also `header('Location: http://www.calvindeveloping.tk/fr/index.php');`

Comment: it seems my web hostin service server is down for the while so i cant see the actual message now